# Drupal 7 drupal_add_tabledrag dragging but not dropping

Tags: 7, forms

I am trying to use the drupal_add_tabledrag in a form table, the dragging is added fine, but dropping is not working

```
$entity_ids = range(10,20); // Loading dummy data

$entities = entity_load('node', $entity_ids);
$rows = array();

foreach ($entities as $id => $entity) {
    $rows[$id] = array(
        'data' => array($entity->title),
    'class' => array('draggable', 'entity-weight'),
    );
}

$form['settings']['entities'] = array(
    '#tree' => TRUE,
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => array(t('Title')),
    '#rows' => $rows,
    '#attributes' => array('id' => 'entity_table')
);

$form['settings']['title'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Find entity'),
    '#autocomplete_path' => 'list_bean/autocomplete',
);

drupal_add_tabledrag('entity_table', 'order', 'self', 'entity-weight');

return $form;
```

I can rearrange items using drag, but I cannot drop the item I drag, it sticks tot he cursor.

Comment: Try updating your jQuery version. I have seen such issues and changing jQuery version fixed it.

Comment: I have the same problem but updating the jquery version did not help